# Is the line between a discussion based question and a definitive answer question fuzzy?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I know StackExchange has a pretty strict policy about discussion based questions, as I [recently discovered](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/252250/where-to-find-introductions-to-seemingly-general-programming-knowledge). It got me thinking, how does the StackExchange community define opinion-based or *bad* questions? Without a strict line between what is opinion-based and what isn't a lot of questions that have been answered on StackExchange can be considered opinion based.

There are numerous questions about Best Practices for example. Some of these questions pose arguments for or against doing something and give sufficient background information to allow an answer to be a "Best" answer. Some of them however don't, and yet aren't considered opinion based questions. In fact, any Best Practice question has an infinite number of answers that are valid which can be infinitely disagreed upon by others and turned into a discussion.

Even the act of determining if a question is opinion-based can be boiled down to an opinion. One person may think a question is opinion-based while another doesn't.

Of course, everything I've said here doesn't apply to every question, only a select few "fuzzy" questions. As with almost everything in life there are the extreme ends of the spectrum; the questions that have clearly well defined answer like "What is 2 + 2", and the questions that are purely opinion based like "What is your favourite colour", but in the middle things can get wonky.

So how does StackExchange define opinion based and how does it handle questions that are in the fuzzy zone?

I'm probably just butthurt that my question got took down.

Comment: Wrt best practices, see [Why is asking a question on “best practice” a bad thing?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/165773)

Comment: @gnat damn, that's an exact duplicate.

Comment: you should have guessed that you're not the first to wonder about this :)